# scala: Any default apply method in a class?

Tags: scala

Does scala provide a default apply method for a class?

I have a class:

```
class Player(tea: String, sal: Int = 0) {
    val team  = tea
    private val salary = sal
}
```

So no apply method here, and I haven't defined any companion object for it, so no apply method from there too.

But I am able to do:

```
val player = Player("AAAA", 1000)
```

With no 'new' operator used, I understand that this line of code must invoke some apply method. But there is none defined  by me. So how does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since Scala 3, as described in the [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/creator-applications.html):

> Scala case classes generate apply methods, so that values of case classes can be created using simple function application, without needing to write `new`.

> Scala 3 generalizes this scheme to all concrete classes. Example:

```scala
class StringBuilder(s: String):
  def this() = this("")

StringBuilder("abc")  // old: new StringBuilder("abc")
StringBuilder()       // old: new StringBuilder()
```

> This works since a companion object with two apply methods is generated together with the class. The object looks like this:

```scala
object StringBuilder:
  inline def apply(s: String): StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s)
  inline def apply(): StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
```

> The synthetic object StringBuilder and its apply methods are called constructor proxies. Constructor proxies are generated even for Java classes and classes coming from Scala 2. The precise rules are as follows:

> 1. A constructor proxy companion object `object C` is created for a concrete class `C`, provided the class does not have already a companion, and there is also no other value or method named `C` defined or inherited in the scope where `C` is defined.
> 2. Constructor proxy `apply` methods are generated for a concrete class provided
>
>    - the class has a companion object (which might have been generated in step 1), and
>    - that companion object does not already define a member named `apply`.

> Each generated `apply` method forwards to one constructor of the class. It has the same type and value parameters as the constructor.

Comment: It's worth noting that Scala 3 is less aggressive in generating `apply` methods for non-`case` classes. That is, for a `case class`, it *always* generates the corresponding `apply` methods, but for non-`case` classes, it won't generate any synthetic `apply` methods if there are already any `apply` overloads manually defined on the companion object. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Mercerenies/febf45eeb04e7877dd330476fd1c40be) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more rule to an already exhaustive list...:(....btw, doc also says "This works since a companion object with two apply methods is generated together with the class. "..I guess creation of a companion object is also a new feature, as scala 2 doesn't create one, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Mandroid ΤΒΗ have not dug that deep, so can't answer.